# How do I define a prop at the level of a component?

Tags: templates, reactjs

I'm using multiple levels of React JSX templates as my views for an Express application (with https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views), and want to know what the best way to pass a prop from the lowest level template (default.jsx, in the example on GitHub and for my project) to all the templates that use `{this.props.children}`. I'm pretty sure putting it in at the default.jsx level.

My problem is: I don't know what the proper way to define a prop (the one I want to do is `siteName`) is without using the `<CustomComponent prop="prop value">` syntax is. What is the proper way to do that on the same level/in the same file as the component? Or is there a level of abstraction that I'm missing? Code is below.

`/views/layouts/default.jsx` (where I want to define siteHeader, and have it propagate all the way down):

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var SiteHeader = require('../header.jsx');

var DefaultLayout = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <h1>{this.props.siteName} - {this.props.title}</h1>
                </head>
                <body>
                <SiteHeader></SiteHeader>
                {this.props.children}
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = DefaultLayout;
```

`/views/index.jsx`:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var DefaultLayout = require('./layouts/default.jsx');

var ViewsExport = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
                <div>Hello, {this.props.name}!</div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = ViewsExport;
```

`/views/header.jsx`:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var SiteHeader = React.createClass({
    return: function() {
        <header>
            <h1><a href="">{this.props.siteName}<h1>
            <nav>
                ...
            </nav>
        </header>
    }
});
```

`/routes/index.js`:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { /* props */ });
};
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve. You can [transfer all props](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html) from owner component to his children by writing: `return <Component {...this.props} more="values" />;`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think what you are looking for is React [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/03/28/the-road-to-1.0.html#context).

> While we haven't documented context, it exists in some form in
>   React already. It exists as a way to pass values through a tree
>   without having to use props at every single point. We've seen this
>   need crop up time and time again, so we want to make this as easy as
>   possible. It's use has performance tradeoffs, and there are known
>   weaknesses in our implementation, so we want to make sure this is a
>   solid feature.

See also http://davehking.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html

It is not officially released yet as it seems to have some corner case problems but is actually used by many people and frameworks build on top of React. I also use it and did not notice any bug yet. A React team member told me that the feature is not gonna be removed, so the API may change but you can still expect this feature to be present in the next versions.

Comment: Context (or impractical purity) is unfortunately required for server side rendering because singletons don't play nice with node.js.  If you use it, make sure to lock in an exact react version, and read the detailed release notes before upgrading.